# The following compromised line isn't working as expected

Tags: reactjs

I'm new in React js I need your explanation for the following code:

The following compromised line is n't working as expected:

```
setPersonstate({person:Personstate.person.splice(index,1),show:Personstate.show})
```

But when I divide it into lines it works fine

```
const personsarr = Personstate.person
personsarr.splice(index,1)
setPersonstate({person:personsarr,show:Personstate.show})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Array#splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method returns an Array of the removed elements.

So in your "compromised" line, the person will result in an Array with the removed person. While in your second snippet, the person gets set to the `personarr` without the removed element.

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to achieve, are you trying to remove a person from the Array or are you trying to select a single person?

Comment: Thanks @Christiaan for your answer, sorry for being late :(